# ObjectInputStream Invalid Stream Header: 00000000

Tags: java

I want to use a single ObjectInputStream to read from a byte array, but I keep getting a StreamCorruptedException every time I start the program.

```
public void run(){

        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[65535];

        bIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(receiveBuffer);

        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bIn);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(true){
            try {
                packetIn = new DatagramPacket(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.length);
                sock.receive(packetIn);

                Object o = in.readObject();
                //do things with o
            }
        }
}
```

I'm just trying to initialize the ObjectInputStream to read from the byte array eventually, but it's throwing that exception even if I remove the while loop.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you take a look at the javadocs for the [`ObjectInputStream(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#ObjectInputStream%28java.io.InputStream%29) constructor, you'll see:

> Creates an ObjectInputStream that reads from the specified InputStream. **A serialization stream header is read from the stream** and verified. This constructor will block until the corresponding ObjectOutputStream has written and flushed the header.
>
> ...
>
> throws
>
> `StreamCorruptedException` - if the stream header is incorrect

(emphasis added)

In other words, the constructor doesn't just record the `InputStream` reference you give it, it also reads from that object. In this case, that's a stream of all `0`s.

You should defer creating the `ObjectInputStream` until you have the serialized data (or at least enough of it to read the header).

(In the interest of "teach a person to fish," I'll also note that any time a method/constructor throws an exception you don't expect, that method's javadocs are a good place to start for understanding its behavior. The javadocs for the JDK classes are usually pretty good.)

Comment: So you're saying use the socket input stream and gather all the bytes coming in, and then create the object input stream to read the bytes and get the object? Is this correct? Basically buffer it first?

Comment: That's one solution. Another is to not create the reader until the stream is ready to be read.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, this is how object streams work and the solution that works everywhere.

Object stream data is preceded by a 4 byte 'magical' sequence AC ED 00 05. An ObjectInputStream will peek for this data at construction time rather than before the first read. And that's logical: one wants to be sure it is a proper stream before being too far in an application. The sequence is buffered by the ObjectOutputStream at construction time so that it is pushed on the stream at the first write. This method often leads to complexities in buffered situations or transferring via pipes or sockets. Fortunately, there is a just as simple as an effective solution to all these problems:

Flush the ObjectOutputStream immediately after construction!

```
ObjectOutputStream myStream = new ObjectOutputStream ( anotherStream );
myStream.flush();
```

In your case, you will have to use a **ObjectOutputStream** if you want to read from an ObjectInputStream

Comment: what do you mean by anotherStream ??

Answer (score 3):

The stream protocol includes a stream header, which `ObjectInputStream` reads in the constructor. You have to defer creating the stream until you have received something:

```
    sock.receive(packetIn);

    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(bIn);
        Object o = in.readObject();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```