# StreamCorruptedException when using ObjectInputStream in socket server side programming

Tags: java, sockets, server

I am writing a socket server side programming where client first send int 1 for case 1 for registration and sent a  array of string object. Then I store that information into the file and return an object with further information back to the client.

But the problem is when client connect and type any number then, **StreamCorruptedException** exception occurs.

I deleted all the lines inside the while loop except the getInt line to receive the input from client then also the same error occurs.

The exception is

**java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000**

```
  try{

        inputFromClient = new DataInputStream( new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream())); 
    outputToClient  = new DataOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream
                                    (socket.getOutputStream()));

    objOutputToClient  = new ObjectOutputStream( new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));
    objOutputToClient.flush();
    objOutputToClient.reset();


    try{
         //the exception occurs here
        //the java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 00000000

        objInputFromClient  = new ObjectInputStream( new
        BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        objInputFromClient.reset();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Exception in HandleAClient " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();           
    } 

   while( true ){
        int getInt = inputFromClient.readInt();     

        switch ( getInt ){
        case 1 : // Get object for registration
            object = objInputFromClient.readObject();

            string = registerLogin.register(socket, object);                
            objOutputToClient.writeObject(string);
            break;
             default: string[0] = "9";
            objOutputToClient.writeObject(string);
           }
    }
   }
  catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Exception in HandleAClient " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();           
    } 

catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception in HandleAClient" + e);
    e.printStackTrace();   
}
```

the code which create a problem is this only:

```
    objInputFromClient  = new ObjectInputStream( new BufferedInputStream 
    (socket.getInputStream()));
```

Comment: You are not supposed to create more than one object for the input stream and one for the output stream.

Comment: possibly  relevant:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635198/objectinputstream-invalid-stream-header-00000000